# Stomp.Net example: need explanation

Tags: c#, stomp

I test [STOMP example Stomp.Net.Example.SendReceiveCore](https://github.com/DaveSenn/Stomp.Net/blob/master/.Src/Examples/Stomp.Net.Example.SendReceiveCore/Program.cs). In connection factory:

```
SslSettings =
{
  ServerName = serverName,
  ClientCertSubject = subject,
  KeyStoreName = "My",
  KeyStoreLocation = "LocalMachine"
}
```

What should be in `ClientCertSubject`? In certificate properties, I see `Subject` is `CN = fpclientcert` (value `fpclientcert`). Submitting that value gives error:

> [Warn]  Found no matching cert. with Subject 'fpclientcert'    (SelectLocalCertificate Ln 161 [C:_git\Stomp.Net.Src\Stomp.Net\Transport\SslTransport.cs])

Certificate was created and imported into trust store on a server. Exported client's certificate has been imported into Personal store on client machine. 
I can establish connection with that certificates using `SslStream` socket.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It looks like match my requirements

Comment: Can help anybody? I really tired trying to get working activemq ssl connection either using nms and stomp

Comment: Well, I resolved issue with subject. Now, I have error related to SslProtocol version. It is default, but I need to set it to Tls12. Please, how should I set it in that above Stomp example code?